# Usage of c++17 precompiled headers in an older g++-environment

Tags: g++, static-libraries, precompiled-headers

[X-problem:](http://xyproblem.info/) 
*Generating a library out of a cpp-headerfile.*

Y-problem: Is it possible to make c++17-features available in a *non-c++17* environment?

I've tried this via a precompiled header-file:

```
$ g++-8 -c ../header.hpp -std=c++17 -fconcepts
```

This generates a ~22 MB .hpp.gch file, which I can use here:

```
$ g++-8 main.cpp -Wall -Winvalid-pch
```

But this does not work without `-std=c++17`.

**Additional note**:
Assume that `header.hpp` contains something like this:

```
template <typename A>
bool Function::Call( const A *const a) {
     if constexpr (std::is_same_v<double, A>) ...
```

`ìf constexpr` is syntax which only works for a standard greater or equal than c++17

Comment: I am using the g++-8 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04) 8.3.0 compiler.

Comment: `if constexpr` available starting from GCC 7 (i.e. you need C++ 17). Which GCC version you have to use ? In case of 4.8 -  i think you would have to rewrite the code  to replace `if constexpr` with recursion constexpr functions. Precompiled headers  are not object files.